# Router constantly blinking red. Can't connect to it in any way

Tags: router

I bought a mini router/repeater/USB router from Dlink (DIR-518L) and after I upgraded its firmware via the web interface it doesn't work anymore.

The light on the device keeps blinking red but holding the Reset button pressed doesn't do anything (Either turned off or on, with or without internet connection).

Plugging my ethernet cable from the PC into it yields no result and keeps on "Identifying..." (Win10). Troubleshooting with the windows troubleshooter tells me "Ethernet" doesn't have a valid IP configuration.

The WiFi on the hotspot is not active either. Any idea on what I could do with it to bring it back to life?

https://www.router-reset.com/en/reset-manuals/D-Link/DIR-518L-rev-A1 I tried to reset it using these instructions as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have "bricked" your router  (its in "recovery mode" which is not well documented for this router - [the manual](https://fccid.io/pdf.php?id=2138132) does not even describe blinking red, it describes sold red asa being defective - outer DLink routers have a flashing red light indicating recovery mode).  As you are asking this question in the SU forum, the answer is most likely "you need to send the router back to Dlink or just get another router".

If you are incredibly lucky, you may be able to get a working version of the firmware, statically configure your computer to an ip address of 192.168.0.2 (netmask 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.0.1), go to http://192.168.0.1 and upload the firmware through a web interface.

From a technical POV, the solution is to somehow upload good firmware on to the router.  On  a bricked router this ranges from tricky to impossible.   Depending on the exact hardware If you can find the firmware, you can sometimes open the router up and connect to a JTAG port and flash the firmware (if you have the appropriate hardware and are able to expose the JTAG port - which sometimes requires basic soldering).  This router does apparently have a serial port - which most likely is a JTAG port.    Quite frankly, for a router released 4 years ago and which costs less then US$75 to replace, its probably not worth the time or effort unless you want to do it as a learning experience

Also, as this device is not even listed in the DD-WRT or OpenWRT sites,  getting help from a knowledgeable community for it will be very difficult.

Comment: Seconding the opinion on biting the cost on a new router. It's not worth trying to get this 4 year old device working, especially with how WiFi technology has evolved since then.